# Clopen sets of an infinite set with cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite set with its cofinite topology. I was asked to mention the clopen sets. I think the only clopen sets are X and the empty set, because otherwise, if A is a clopen set, it would mean that both A and its complentary set are finite, so their union, which is X, is finite - a contradiction. Am I right? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you are right (and maybe should have more faith in your mathematical skills).